# Why Ctrl+ / doesn't work in my Mathematica?

Tags: formatting, keyboard

I would like to type a fraction into my notebook using the Ctrl + / combination, but it doesn't work.[image]

Comment: Which version of Mathematica and what operating system? Possibly even the keyboard layout may matter. It works for me on MacOS, Mathematica 12.

Comment: Did you even modify anything within Mathematica's installation directory?

Comment: Make sure you are not literally typing "+". Ctrl+/ means to hold down the control key followed by a slash (no plus sign involved).

Comment: @C.E. I'm using version 11.3 on Windows OS.

Comment: @Szabolcs Not really!

Comment: "Not really!" So is that a clear "no", or "just a little bit"? Also, did you ever install any packages that affect menu items or shortcut keys? Anything special in your `$UserBaseDirectory/FrontEnd`?

Comment: You should explicitly point out that the shortcut is missing from the menu. It seems to me that several people did not notice this from the photo you inserted. Also, a screenshot is much clearer than a smartphone photo ...

Comment: What input language (aka keyboard layout) are you using?